# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type octave_interrupt_exception

Tags: java, octave, macports, osx-yosemite

Hi I used macport to install octave 3.8.2 on my mac running Yosemite.
The installation was successful. However, every time when I ctrl+z to terminate octave I get the following error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type octave_interrupt_exception
>   Abort trap:6

I am not sure this happens. But I was using javaoctave to invoke octave in my java program. Terminating with an exception does not allow me to pass the values calculated properly back to java.

I hope someone is able to help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-z does not terminate the running application.  It sends the process SIGTSTP which puts it in the background, suspended.  It's likely that octave does not properly handle SIGTSTP and thus aborts.  You should quit the application via normal means rather than hitting ctrl-z at the terminal.

Comment: Actually when I quit by typing exit I will also get the same problem

Comment: Then look at the crash log to see the backtrace, hopefully showing where the exception was thrown from or at least logging the failure reason with more detail.  It should be in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports